# Google Analytics; creating a segment using multiple ids

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to get google analytics on a small set of pages, of the thousands of pages, tracked by the google analytics. Each of these page has a unique id and I was hoping to use these to identify the subset of pages. Following are examples of such ids.

- uda502aaf-3a8f-4aa5-9f49-00d2ac4c6545
  ud5655462-c5f5-46c4-b807-d1a8527786d7
  uceb1a469-0af9-499f-9608-42242a9f0c63
  uc4b4d9e3-a558-4282-a009-e984e81364eb
  ubaf6e057-4cad-4b9b-a625-7b2ea11fa8c5
  ub1c4cb68-bc41-476b-9e31-9b9800113236
  uadb6c44d-792b-48ca-969d-ff1b638dd223
  uaa17490f-11ff-4947-9841-9f744963fbc2
  u9a60d135-64f7-4890-963f-8093b8cf1eaa

I tried to create a filter on pages, using "contains", with the ids separated by | as shown below

A) 
uf07f4d74-2239-4b4b-851f-d40e51ad5f9a | 125bd8a07b4c32917dae805c23ead087  |  c65da9b1fcb588e64cb126fda78afee9

AND

B)
(uf07f4d74-2239-4b4b-851f-d40e51ad5f9a) | (125bd8a07b4c32917dae805c23ead087) | (c65da9b1fcb588e64cb126fda78afee9)

and everything was "0". I know users have visited these pages.  How can I create a correct filter for such IDs?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a "contains" filter type if you have multiple IDs that you want to sort through. In your example A, you are using something like a Regex format, so you should select "Matching RegExp" as the filter type.

Comment: Thanks nyuen, With regex and escape (\\) for - I get the desired result.